# Apache mod_rewrite HTTP sequence of rules

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a rule set in .htaccess which would treat a URL differently depending on the HTTP_REFERER value. Something is not working as expected, and I'm not sure if the problem is syntactic or logical.

In simple terms, for all files under a specific directory I want them to be served straight up if the HTTP_REFERER is from the same domain, or redirect to a script if it's blank or other domain. What I have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://%{HTTP_HOST}.*$
RewriteRule ^/mydir/(.+)$ /incl/serve_content.php?c=$1 [L]
```

The site is HTTPS only, so the *https* in the condition should be enough. What I get though is that the rule never seems to match. What am I missing?

**Edit**

After more debugging, it looks like this rule does not even get checked, there is no mention of neither match nor no-match in the log file created by the RewriteLog directive. Why wouldn't it check it it?

**Edit** The complete contents of the `.htaccess` file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /incl/404.php

AddType application/octet-stream .csv
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet .xlsx

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://%{HTTP_HOST}.*$
RewriteRule ^/mydir/(.+)$ /incl/serve_content.php?c=$1 [L]


RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^final/([A-Za-z0-9_\.]+)$ incl/serve_final.php?c=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^quiz/([A-Za-z0-9_\.]+)/([0-9]+)$ incl/serve_quiz.php?c=$1&q=$2 [QSA]
```

Comment: Is it correct that you only want a redirect to occur if the HTTP_REFERER is the current site (HTTP_HOST) running on https? or are you trying to handel third party referrers ?

Comment: I only want to redirect third party or empty referrers.

Answer (score 2):

When you're working with mod_rewrite, the most important directives you have is

```
 RewriteLog /path/to/apachelogs/rewrite.log
 RewriteLogLevel 9
```

This will give you a huge amount of debug information. If you add those lines and then look at the debug log, you should find exactly what is going on and hopefully get some hints to why.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It looks like the condition is not being checked at all. I have another rule in the same file (for forcing https) and I can see how it's being checked in the log file, but nothing about this rule. Hm...

Comment: Can you post all your rewrite rules in the order they appear in the config file? There may be clues there.

Answer (score 2):

The rule will never match because you're using a leading slash in an `.htaccess` file.  Try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^mydir/(.+)$ incl/serve_content.php?c=$1 [L]
```

By the way, if you have access to the server config, [you shouldn't be using `.htaccess`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/howto/htaccess.html#when).